# Geany support for Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, geany

- [GitHub Geany -- Kotlin Language Support #1581](https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/1581)
- [MGitHub Geany -- Add Kotlin custom filetype from github.com/esotericpig #2186](https://github.com/geany/geany/pull/2186)
- [Scintilla -- #1224 Kotlin & Groovy langs](https://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/feature-requests/1224/)

What is the status of [Kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language)) support in [Geany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany)? Is there a manual way to add it until it is supported?